# ServiceProvider.GetService returns the same instance for scoped service in transient instance factory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In asp.net core 3.1 project, I have the following controller (ctor):

```cs
public MyController(IMyService myService) { }
```

The `IMyService` interface and `MyService`

```cs
public interface IMyService { }

public class MyService : IMyService { }
```

Where the `IService` is registered in my `Startup.cs` as follows:

```cs
services.AddScoped<MyService>();
services.AddTransient(sp =>
                      {
                          var service = sp.GetRequiredService<MyService>();
                          // do something on the service...
                          return service as IMyService;
                      });
```

However, when I'm doing multiple requests, I see that only the first request is initiating a new instance of the `MyService` (i.e., when I'm putting a breakpoint in the `MyService` constructor, it will break only on the first request).

The thing that bugs me the most, is that if I'm changing the `services.AddTransient(sp => ...` line in the `Startup.cs` file to `services.AddScoped(sp => ...` - everything works and the instance is initiated every request.

How can I fix the issue so when I'm getting services inside the instance factory, it will be gathered by the correct scope of the request?

Comment: Was not able to reproduce - in my simple repro the breakpoint is hit every time. Can you post repro? Also I would highly recommend not to resolve scoped services for transient ones - it can fail if transient one will be resolved from the root scope.

Comment: I've tried again on a clean project and it seems that you're right, it would not reproduce.
I then find out that in my project there was a usage in UnityContainer, and that what messed things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @GuruStron comment, I found out that I have the following line in my `Program.cs`, although I'm not really using Unity container in my project:

```cs
.UseUnityServiceProvider()
```

after I removed this line, everything works as expected.